# What is this Kotlin type: (String..String?)

Tags: kotlin, types, syntax, nullable, kotlin-null-safety

IntelliJ is showing me context hints that my variables are of type `(String..String?)`. I cannot find any mention of it on the internet, what is this type?

[image]

Comment: What is the type of `payload.email`?

Comment: @Endzeit It is `public String getEmail()`. It might be a Java-Kotlin translation

Comment: Is the type definition written in Java, by any chance? When using Java from Kotlin types are often written as `String!` because Kotlin cannot know if these platform types are nullable or not. Maybe that is a different notation for it? It would make some sense, meaning any type between non-nullable and nullable String. However, I've never seen this representation myself.

Comment: I don't think it's valid Kotlin code: [playground](https://pl.kotl.in/Je7U4yBF5). Mysterious.

Comment: @Thomas It's a hint by IntellJ IDEA, not Kotlin code. IntelliJ also uses `String!` to denote platform types, which is not valid Kotlin syntax either.

Comment: Are you able to write `val email: String? = payload.email`?

Comment: what do `email is String` and `email is String?` return? 2xtrue means it's String, false true that it's String?, 2xfalse - no clue (see https://pl.kotl.in/ymOft6Bp7). My gut feel says it's related to the Java not being null specific

Comment: @Stachu this is not correct. Those `is` checks will depend on the *current value* returned by `payload.email`, not its *type*. So you'll get `true`/`true` if email is not null at this moment, and get `false`/`true` if email is null. In the first case, you can't assume the string could never have been null. You can't know the actual intended type unless you look at the corresponding Java code and its invariants/intention

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`(String..String?)` represents a [flexible type](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/type-system.html#flexible-types) with lower bound `String` and upperbound `String?` (nullable string). This is not valid Kotlin code (it's not *denotable*) but it is used in the compiler internals and thus in IntelliJ's hints sometimes.

(On the JVM we often see *platform types* using `!` as in `String!`, which are a more specific case of flexible types)

It's Kotlin's way of saying it doesn't know whether the `String` type declared for `payload.email` is nullable or not (for instance if this is declared in Java, which doesn't distinguish those), and yet it doesn't want to enforce either of those, for convenience (hence "flexible").

> As the name suggests, flexible types are flexible — a value of type (L..U) can be used in any context, where one of the possible types between L and U is needed

This means that even though the actual type of the value is *"somewhere between `String` and `String?`"*, values of this type can be used even in places expecting `String`, even though the real type of that value may be `String?` and thus the value could be null.

This is useful because assuming it is `String` would mean that null checks would be marked as redundant, and assuming it is `String?` would force the developer to write null checks everywhere, even though they might know that this particular Java method cannot return null.

In general, it's a good practice to explicitly declare the type of a variable that you get from Java, to avoid the propagation of the platform type and the uncertainty (and unsafety) that comes with it:

```kotlin
val email: String = payload.email // if you know it cannot be null
val email: String? = payload.email // if you don't know
```